# Tableau - show months with null values in bar chart

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have created a bar chart showing a count of instances during a filtered list of months.  However, where there is no data for a month it will only display the months (using show missing values) between a start and and end date where data resides.  but for example if I have no data for Dec and Jan, but data for Nov, Nov is the last month i see.

is there anyway to show all months in the filter regardless of data being present?

[chart showing missing values, but only between actual values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdbNa.png)

I have created a bar chart showing a count of instances during a filtered list of months.  However, where there is no data for a month it will only display the months (using show missing values)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution for this, although not ideal I was to fix the Axis by right clicking on the axis -> Edit Axis -> set as fixed with a start and end date

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0D9M.png)

Ideally I would have liked to be able to control this from the filter options, but this will have to do for now unless anyone else has a better solution?